# Machine shows up in router but no responding to ping and any other connections

Tags: networking

Well, the machine is not technically a server, just a normal pc box running linux. I left that machine on in my apartment when I went home for the summer. However, about one month later, I realized that I cannot ssh into my machine any more. I logged into my router, saw my machine is actually on the client list (the link state of the port on which my machine is connected to is actually showing "1000 Full Duplex", which means NIC is sort of up), and assigned an IP (I tried rebooting my router several times, my machine still shows up every time). However, when I tries to ping my machine from my router, my machine never responded.

```
$ ping 192.168.1.2
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2): 56 data bytes
```

And when I tries to ssh into my machine, it hangs.

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.2 -vvv
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.2 port 22.
```

Since I have no physical access to my machine, I cannot inspect it personally. Just wondering what's possible reasons for causing this? (it's kind of weird because it seems like the NIC is down, but it shouldn't be able to respond to the router)

Comment: After you ping it, can you see if it's in your ARP table?  Do `arp -an | grep 192.168.1.2`.

Comment: yes. it shows ? (192.168.1.2) at (my machine's mac address) [ether]  on br0

Comment: So your machine is running-ish, as it's able to send ARP replies, but apparently unable to open a TCP connection.  I take it you've tried connecting to its port 22 from your router?

Comment: Correct. I was trying to ssh from my router.

Comment: And did you check your firewall? (log is best, or settings are good too, esp. to verify logging is enabled)

Comment: Are you sure your SSH daemon is accepting connections on port 22? This looks a lot like a connection trying to connect to a non-listening port.

Comment: @bjanssen well, the problem is that it was working for the whole month, then it suddenly stopped working. Also other services stopped working as well, like OpenVPN server running on my machine.